# Problem with firewall on app using jersey and deployed at weblogic

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic, firewall

I have an app using jersey 1.x to consume external API. This app is deployed at weblogic 12.1.2. 
Everthing work well until I have to deploy it on enviroment that have to pass through a firewall.
Using jersey, for some reason, when the request reaches the firewall, URL is already with dns resolution to IP and the firewall rule deny because it need an URL.
I have tried the same request in a jar project with main and run it on the same server and it worked.
The problem is just when I run it with jersey, whatever jersey 1 or 2, both fails when deployed on weblogic.
I tried the apache http deployed on the weblogic and it worked.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

This code work on a jar with main and do not work deployed on weblogic. 
That same simple request using Apache http work when deployed on weblogic.
Remenber that the problem is that the URL is being resolved to IP before it reaches the firewall.

```
        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("https://xxx.yyy.com/consent/v1/oauth/access-token");

        String input = "{\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\",\"code\":\"d27bd61a-594b-337e-b94f-70e686189816\",\"refresh_token\":null}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
```